# Excel - language specific date formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i want to use a formula that writes ID containing date but the file is shared with ppl that has computer in english or german.

i tried adding a language tag but it still does not work

`="3_"&TEXT(C2;"[$-407]JJJJMMTT")&"_"&TEXT(F2;"0")&"_"&D2&"_"&G2&"_"&P2`

shows 3_JJJJ03TT_30_BVH_R_16064102 where "JJJJ" should be year and "TT" day.

Am i using the language tag wrong?

Comment: Did you test what happens if you use the English tags instead? (YYYYMMDD)

Comment: I think using `e` for the year will be universal for everyone. `="3_"&TEXT(C2;"[$-407]eeeeMMTT")&"_"&TEXT(F2;"0")&"_"&D2&"_"&G2&"_"&P2`. can you try and let me know

Comment: You could create an UDF in VBA. VBA works always in English but the returned output would be displayed in any language settings.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yes, since i have pc in english, YYYMMDD works for me, but does not for those that have pc in German.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thank you, that helps with the year! but still the days are as "TT".

Comment: Well, doesn't `dd` works for all ?